# How to access webpack environmental variables in nativescript?

Tags: angular, webpack, nativescript

I want to store an environmental variable in webpack.config.js, that I will set when I bundle the app with webpack in Nativescript. The goal is to keep the environmental variable secret even after the bundle.

How do I do that?

I believe this should be possible, as described (but not detailed) here: https://docs.nativescript.org/performance-optimizations/bundling-with-webpack.

But I am not able to get it to work in testing. I am new to webpack, so I may be missing something obvious.

To keep it simple, I am going to call the variable 'simple_env_variable', and give it a value 'here_is_the_value!'.

To access this variable, I had thought I would call it with:

```
$ tns build ios --bundle --env.development --env.simple_env_variable=here_is_the_value!
```

What code do I enter in webpack.config.js, and then what code do I enter in my ts component to access it?

For example:

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = env => {
...
  const config = {
  ...
   plugins: [
   ...
     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "simple_env_variable": /**What Do I Enter Here***/
```

cool-component.ts:

```
export class CoolComponent {

public myVariable = /**What Do I enter here to access the variable in webpack.config.js? **/
```

Comment: you cant access. You'll have to use defineplugin and process.env variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Nick Lliev's answer as a starting point, and from the discussion [here](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/best-practice-for-secrets-like-using-environmental-variables/6997/22), the following worked for me after upgrading my webpack and nativescript settings:

webpack.config.js:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "global.TNS_WEBPACK": "true",
        "process": undefined,
        "myGlobal.MySecret": JSON.stringify(env.first_property)
}),
```

main-page.ts:

```
import {OnInit...

declare let myGlobal: any

@Component...

export class MainPageComponent implements OnInit {
...

ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log(myGlobal.MySecret) // prints "yaySecret" with the run command I have below
}
```

Then the working tns run command:

```
$ tns run ios --bundle --env.uglify --env.aot --env.first_property="yaySecret"
```

Comment: I get myGlobal is not defined error when I followed above sample. Any idea why is that?

Comment: That error appears for me when I have a typo regarding the variable, either: 1) in the tns command, 2) in the webpack config file or 3) in the component ts file. It's saying that the variable you are passing in the component ts file has not been defined, so look at where you have defined it (in those three spots)

Comment: It works now. Thanks. Not sure what I was missing:)

Answer (score 3):

You can directly access the key-value pair in your code but if you are using TypeScript you should cast it to any (as TS needs strong typing for all variables).

For example

**webpack.config.js**

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                "global.TNS_WEBPACK": "true",
                "process": undefined,
                "myGlobal.MyScarySecret": JSON.stringify("my big old secret")
            }),
```

and then in your bundled application

**main-page.ts**

```
declare let myGlobal: any;

export function navigatingTo(args: EventData) {
    let page = <Page>args.object;

    console.log(myGlobal.MyScarySecret); // my big old secret
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I was able to get your code to work, hardcoding in the value for "myGlobal.MyScarySecret", like you have done. How do I do this while keeping the value out of my source code? (Given that is the main goal--keeping that value a secret.) What would be the terminal bundle command? (ie, $ tns build ios --bundle --???)

Comment: Following up on what would be the correct terminal bundle command? Online sources don't nail it down, and my attempts so far have yielded errors. Thanks.

Comment: @9gt53wS I'm using your method and accessing `myGlobal` value inside my service `ApolloService` and running the app. But it is throwing an error
`Reference Error: myGlobal is not defined at new ApolloService`. Please help me fix this?

Comment: First I would doublecheck all the defined items: "myGlobal" and "env.first_property" in the webpack.config file, referencing it correctly in the service file, and entering it correctly in the $tns command. If all are correct and you still get error, try updating nativescript and webpack. I got all kinds of errors that were solved with $ tns update. Also check your typescript is the latest version. If all that does not work, try moving the variable from the service directly into component you are using--I don't think that should not make a difference, but I did the below without a service.