# NativeScript - Webpack environment variable not working

Tags: webpack, nativescript

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52102716/5893995) to get the environment variable on the go. I have defined `myGlobal` in my `webpack.config` file.

```
...
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    "global.TNS_WEBPACK": "true",
    "myGlobal.ENV_NAME": JSON.stringify(env.name || "development"),
    "process": undefined,
})
...
```

So now `myGlobal` should be available inside my `.ts` file.
But when I'm logging it inside the constructor of my `ApolloService`. I'm getting a **Reference Error**

**apolloService.ts**

```
declare let myGlobal: any;

@Injectable()
export class ApolloService {


 constructor() {
    console.log(myGlobal.ENV_NAME, '*******'); // Throws Error
 }
```

> Reference Error: myGlobal is not defined at new ApolloService

I'm not able to figure out, where I'm going wrong. Please help!!

Comment: This should work as expected here is a demo for reference https://github.com/NickIliev/NS-Issues-2018-II/tree/master/stackoverflow/global-env

Comment: @NickIliev Exactly same I have done. But still, throwing the same error. Please help me fix this

Comment: Create a Playground demo so I could take a look at ti https://play.nativescript.org/

Comment: If you are running / building with `--bundle` option then `myGlobal.ENV_NAME` will be entirely replaced by the actual value you passed in command line as `--env.name`. The error you are pointing may only happen if you are running without bundle option.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps?

I have setup it like this:

```
//webpack:
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                "global.TNS_WEBPACK": "true",
                'process.env': {
                    'envtype': JSON.stringify(env && env.envtype ? env.envtype : "dev"),
                }                
            }),
```

Then I can acces it in my app:

```
declare var process: any;
if (typeof process !== 'undefined' && process && process.env) {
 console.log(process.env);
}
```

Comment: `typeof process is coming undefined`